# Spark: Round to Decimal in Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataset like below where in case of DataFrame I'm able to easily round to 2 decimal places
but just wondering if there is any easier way to do the same while using typed dataset.

Here is my code snippet:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.scalalang.typed.{sum => typedSum}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DecimalType}

case class Record(BOOK: String,ID: String,CCY: String,AMT: Double)  

def getDouble(num: Double) = {BigDecimal(num).setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble}    

val ds = Seq(
("ALBIBC","1950363","USD",2339055.7945),
("ALBIBC","1950363","USD",78264623778.813345),
("ALBIBC","1950363","USD",45439055.222),
("ALBIBC","1950363","EUR",746754759055.343),
("ALBIBC","1950363","EUR",343439055.88780),
).toDS("BOOK","ID","CCY","AMT")
```

Dataframe way produces the following output:

```
val df: DataFrame = data.groupBy('BOOK,'ID,'CCY).agg(sum('AMT).cast(DecimalType(38,2)).as("Balance"))
df.show()

+------+-------+---+---------------+
|  BOOK|     ID|CCY|        Balance|
+------+-------+---+---------------+
|ALBIBC|1950363|USD| 78312401889.83|
|ALBIBC|1950363|EUR|747098198111.23|
+------+-------+---+---------------+
```

How would I go about rounding the balance to 2 decimal places in case of dataset?

```
val sumBalance = typedSum[Record](_.AMT).as[Double].name("Balance")
val ds = data.groupByKey(thor => (thor.BOOK, thor.ID, thor.CCY)).agg(sumBalance.name("Balance"))
               .map{case(key,value) => (key._1,key._2,key._3,getDouble(value))}
ds.show()   

+------+-------+---+------------------+
|    _1|     _2| _3|                _4|
+------+-------+---+------------------+
|ALBIBC|1950363|USD| 7.831240188983E10|
|ALBIBC|1950363|EUR|7.4709819811123E11|
+------+-------+---+------------------+
```

I can go the dataframe way but just curious to know while using Datasets? 
Any advice on this please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is conversion back to `Double`. Floating point representation [cannot represent all possible numbers](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=what+computer+scientiest+should+know+about+fp&ia=web).

Redefine (and probably rename) your function to:

```
def getDouble(num: Double) = BigDecimal(num).setScale(
  2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP
)
```

Example:

```
Seq(7.831240188983E10, 7.4709819811123E11).toDS.map(getDouble).show

// +---------------+           
// |          value|
// +---------------+
// | 78312401889.83|
// |747098198111.23|
// +---------------+
```